# Day difference between to items that belong to a pack

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datediff, items

I'm currently working on a database that has 3 tables:

```
Bottles(**BottleCode**, Dsc, Capacity, BottleDate)
```

The BottleDate column is the date when the bottle was filled.

```
Pack(**PackCode**, PackType, PackDate)
```

The PackDate column is the date when the pack was created.

```
Pack-Bottle(**BottleCode**, **PackCode**)
```

What I want to do is get the PackCode from packs that have a difference of 30 days or more between any of their bottles(BottleDate)

---

I was trying to solve this using DATEDIFF() in SQL Server, but I don't know how to get the oldest and more recent date from the pack, so that I could check if the difference between them is over 30.

I'm really lost, and I would really appreciate if someone could at least point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance :)

Scenario:

Let's say I have a pack with the code "abc123" that contains two bottles one of them was filled on "2014/05/23" and the other one was filled on "2014/09/17", the result should be " abc123" since it contains two bottles that were filled 30 or more days apart from each other, note that a pack has more than just two bottles.

Now lets say I have another pack with the code "efg456" that has three bottles that were filled on "2012/05/04", " 2012/05/15" and "2012/05/28/ respectively, the pack code " efg456" shouldn't appear as a result since all of it's bottles were filled within 30 days apart from each other

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and the expected result?

Comment: Let's say I have a pack with the code "abc123" that contains two bottles one of them was filled on "2014/05/23" and the other one was filled on "2014/09/17", the result should be " abc123" since it contains two bottles that were filled 30 or more days apart from each other, note that a pack has more than just two bottles, thanks, and sorry for my poor english

Comment: Could you include that in your question? Together with some more scenarios.

Comment: Sure, sorry I'm new around here

Comment: Could you provide sample data for each of your tables? That way, the answer will be directly applicable to your table design.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method using an `exists` clause:

```
select p.*
from packs p
where exists (select 1
              from packbottle pb join
                   bottle b
                   on pb.bottlecode = b.bottlecode
              where pb.packcode = p.packcode and
                    b.bottledate < dateadd(day, -30, p.packdate)
             );
```

Because you want *packs* only and not *bottles*, an `exists` seems like the appropriate solution.

EDIT:

If you want this on any *pair* of bottles, then you don't need the `packs` table at all.  In fact, the query is then just a simple aggregation query with a `having` clause:

```
select pb.packcode, min(bottledate), max(bottledate)
from packbottle pb join
     bottle b
     on pb.bottlecode = p.bottlecode
group by pb.packcode
having datedif(day, min(bottledate), max(bottledate)) > 30
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I explained the situation very well, I have to get de Pack Code from Packs that contain bottles that were filled with a 30 or more days difference, I need to check that the dates from any bottle in the pack are not 30 days appart from each other